# Binary Search in Python - Iterative Method

Tags: python, list

so I'm trying to learn programming myself in Python language and was confused implementing Binary Search in Python. So here's what I have done

```
list = [3,6,8,12,14,17,25,29,31,36,42,47,63,55,62]
key = 42
print(list)

def high(sorted_list):
    max_index = len(sorted_list)
    return max_index
    
def low(sorted_list):
    start_index = 0  
    return start_index  

def mid(sorted_list):
    mid_index = ( low(sorted_list) + (high(sorted_list) - low(sorted_list)) ) // 2
    return mid_index


for x in range(4):
    if list[mid(list)] < key:
        list = list[mid(list)+1:]
    elif list[mid(list)] < key:
        list = list[mid(list)-1:]
    print(list)
```

I know I should not keep a range number in for loop but I know it will only make 4 comparisons in this example so I hardcoded it. But when I run it, it splits the list only once and keep on printing the second half of the list. Output image:

Comment: don't call your list `list`. use `myList` instead. Then I'd recommend that you check your code for errors and understand what it does. You will notice for example that your elif condition is exactly the same as the if condition. making this part of the code never reachable.

Comment: if and elif statements the same here

Comment: `low` doesn't do anything useful; it's a constant function that always returns 0.

Comment: I believe a typo may be the cause of your issue. In your elif I believe it should be `>` instead of `<`

With this change the print output is:
`
    [3, 6, 8, 12, 14, 17, 25, 29, 31, 36, 42, 47, 63, 55, 62]
    [31, 36, 42, 47, 63, 55, 62]
    [42, 47, 63, 55, 62]
    [47, 63, 55, 62]
    [63, 55, 62]
`

Comment: Also, you forgot to check if `lst[mid(lst)] == key`, i.e. you found the key

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I tried your code and had to do a few corrections:

- The `while` loop had to be modified (you knew that)
- There wasn't a check for the case where the key is found (see comments)
- There was a typo, `<` instead of `>` (see comments)
- In the same line, the list partition was wrong
- The `low` function was useless (returning a constant value) (see comments)
- The `high` function was useless too (simply returning the value from another function)
- The `mid` function was more complicated than needed (it boiled down to taking a value, then adding and subtracting zero), so it can simply take the value

Ah, btw the input list is not sorted in your example.

This is my proposal:

```
def mid(lst):
    return len(lst) // 2

def bin_search(lst, k):
    while lst:
        i = mid(lst)
        if lst[i] == k:
            return True
        if lst[i] < k:
            lst = lst[i+1:]
        elif lst[i] > k:
            lst = lst[:i]
    else:
        return False

bin_search([3,6,8,12,14,17,25,29,31,36,42,47,55,62,63], 42)
True

bin_search([3,6,8,12,14,17,25,29,31,36,42,47,55,62,63], 58)
False
```